# Add class to link-to if present

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Trying to convert a Rails app to Ember and got stuck on this simple link when trying to add a class only if not foo.bar is blank:

> link_to "click", foo_path(foo), class: ("bar" if foo.bar?)

How do I convert this to a ember handlebars? obviously

> {{link-to 'click' 'foo.show' foo class="bar" if foo.bar != null}}.

didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

class=foo.someprop:someclass

Check out [this working JS Bin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nabut/2).

Comment: Ty! How do I do if I want to add more classes?

Comment: Yeah but i want to add two custom classes thats not based on prop value.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find a clean & easy way of doing just that, but here's one way of achieving what you wanted: http://jsbin.com/nabut/9/edit